# Eliminar '�' de un archivo txt desde termux

Tags: linux

Me encontré con el problema de ese símbolo �, ya que al usar mi descifrador de contraseñas zip, me lanza un error de que no pudo leer las siguientes palabras.

```py
#Code descifra contraseña del archivo 'Archivo.zip'

import zipfile

import sys

count = 1

with open('rockyou.txt', 'rb') as text:

     for entry in text.readlines():
         password = entry.strip()
         try:
            with zipfile.ZipFile('Archivo.zip', 'r') as zf:
               zf.extractall(pwd=password)
               data = zf.namelist()[0]
               data_size = zf.getinfo(data).file_size
               print ('''password found ~ %s\n ~%s\ ~%s\n'''
                  % (password.decode('utf-8'), data, data_size))
               pass
               break
         except:
            number = count
            print ('[%s] [-]Password failed! - %s' % (number,password.decode('utf-8')))
            count += 1
            pass
```

El número 2468725 es la línea donde se detuvo el script, de aquí a una línea abajo se encuentra la palabra peque�a

```sh
[2468725] [-]Password failed! - zéegui

#error que produce cuando se topa con una palabra como esta: peque�a

Traceback (most recent call last):                  
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/hackzip/script.py", line 12, in <module>
                       zf.extractall(pwd=password)                     File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/zipfile.py", line 1677, in extractall
            self._extract_member(zipinfo, path, pwd)        
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/zipfile.py", line 1730, in _extract_member
       with self.open(member, pwd=pwd) as source,
\           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                 
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/zipfile.py", line 1603, in open
return ZipExtFile(zef_file, mode, zinfo, pwd, True)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                               File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/zipfile.py", line 864, in __init__
               raise RuntimeError("Bad password for file %r" % zipinfo.orig_filename)                          
RuntimeError: Bad password for file 'Archivo'                                                       During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                                   Traceback (most recent call last):
                  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/hackzip/script.py", line 22, in <module>
                       print ('[%s] [-]Password failed! - %s' % (number,password.decode('utf-8')))                                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                       
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

Solo quiero saber cómo eliminar este símbolo '�' del archivo 'rockyou.txt'.

Ya he usado `sed` de todas las formas y nada que elimina ese símbolo.

Comment: Hola Robert, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtengas una mejor respuesta, y de paso evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
De paso, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!,

Comment: Yo no se si no deberías ocuparte de ver de donde salen, ir quitando caracteres sin saber, no me parece buena idea, prueba editar tu pregunta, agregar tu código y seguro alguien te podrá ayudar.

Comment: cuando escribo el código aquí y para luego publicar, tu página no me deja

Comment: Solo dale al botón **editar**, pega el texto, y dale a **guardar**, debería funcionar, no importa si no queda bien identado, nosotros nos encargamos.

Comment: Si el código es muy largo, coloca la parte que es significativa para la solución del problema.

Comment: ya lo escribí, y ahora si lo pude publicar  espero su ayuda

Comment: El problema no es que sobre el caracter, sino que no está pudiendo interpretarlo, osea el entorno no está en "utf-8", modifica eso y te apareceran las "ñ".

Comment: El problema pudiera estar en cómo está codificado el archivo. Intenta, por ejemplo, `with open(el_archivo, 'rb', encoding='utf-8-sig') as text:`. Lo anterior es para utf-8+BOM, también puedes ver [Standard Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/hack_pass_zip/script.py", line 6, in <module>
    with open('prueba_rock.txt', 'rb', encoding='utf-8-sig') as text:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument